# Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 - Sending private message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook SDK v 3.1 in my iphone app, and I want to let the user an option to send a private message to another Facebook user, can't find any thing in the Facebook documentation, and didn't found any complete answer here, any ideas?

Comment: In SDK 3.08 it is not possible to send private message, you can only share message on friends wall, i don't think so that they added this on v3.1

Answer (score 0):

As of Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 this is not possible.